# Assign JavaScript function to document element

Tags: javascript, geolocation, element, document

I have the following code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geofields);
        }
    }

    function geofields() {
        if (document.getElementById('starthere').checked == 1) {
            document.getElementById('start').value = position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('start').value = '';
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want `function geofields(){` to display the GeoLocation, changing the value of 'start' element to the coordinates (received from the GetLocation() script), but it is not working with the code above. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Fix formatting (echk!) 2. Describe "not working"

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: 'Not Working' means the value of the 'start' element does not change to the coordinates, which I am aiming for it to do. And sorry about the formatting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `position` parameter to `geofields` and invoke `getLocation` (or set it as a handler).

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geofields);
    }
}

function geofields(position) {
    if (document.getElementById('starthere').checked == 1) {
        document.getElementById('start').value = position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('start').value = '';
    }
}

document.addEventListener('load', getLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the function call in the onload property on the body element.

```
<body onload="getLocation();">
```

That should ensure the dom has loaded when you execute the function.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation) docs:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

I seems to me that you're not passing the `position` param to your `geofields` function.